# Intensity bloom effect in game doesn't match scene view in Unity

Tags: unity, post-processing

I'm using post-process with the bloom effect and a custom material with emission enabled.

The intensity of the effect in the scene view doesn't match the intensity in the game, as shown in these images.

[image: Screen view]

[image: Game view]

The intensity of the emitter on the material is 2 and the intensity on the post-processing volume is 4. I would expect the object to glow really bright, which is the case in the scene view, but it's barely visible in the game.

The effect does work. If I raise the intensity even higher you can clearly see the glow in-game.

Note that it's a 2D game.

Comment: Do you have any exposure adaptation or colour grading in effect on your camera? This can remap the burned-out colours you're seeing in scene view into a more controlled range (usually desirable if you want a player to be able to look through a window outdoors and see more than just blinding white). Because the burned look is desirable for your game, you might need to change these defaults.

Comment: Are you using URP?

Comment: Are the two images captured from the same display device? Higher pixel-density (which is common in mobile phones) lowers the intensity of blur effects if they weren't coded to consider it.

Comment: I have no other effect on the camera. I made no changes to it, except adding the post-processing layer and volume. I'm not using URP. Both images are made on my laptop.